# Posting a message to a wall from code behind

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a comment from code behind. Is there a way to do this?
I can get the users profile pic by

http://graph.facebook.com/" + fbId + "/picture;

Can I post to a wall in a similar way?

Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using facebook custom application and [Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)

```
            var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(FbConf.testimonialsAppId, FbConf.testimonialsAppSecret);

            IDictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            parameters.Add("message","message on the wall"));
            parameters.Add("created_time", DateTime.Now.ToString());

            dynamic result = facebookClient.Post(string.Format("{0}/feed", FbConf.testimonialsAppId), parameters);
            var id = result.id;
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I got a different answer im gonna post when I can.